# Unity2D stacking movement commands

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
if(CanUp){
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)){
            CanUp = false;
            CanRight = true;
        }
    }else{
     CanRight = true;
    }                  
}

if(CanRight){
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)){
            CanUp = true;
            CanRight = false;
         }
    }else{
        CanUp = true;
    }
}
```

so the idea is that I don't want to have diagonal movement (right now I only have 2 directions but it still doesn't work). When I press W if I press D it works properly, letting me go Right and on D release continuing up, but when I press D first, then I can't go up at all unless I release D, apparently it depends on the position of the if statements but since I am a beginner I can't really think of a solution and I haven't found anything online, please help me

Comment: Hello, can you rephrase your problem please? I did not understand correctly what you want to achieve

Comment: ok, rephrasing it a bit, i want a movement like old Nintendo DS pokemon games, only 4 directions, no diagonal movement. I also want that if i have one key pressed and i press another it ignores the first one and executes the movement associated with the second one, but if i still have both pressed and i release the second one it continues to execute the first movement

Comment: also, it works if the first key i pressed is W but it doesn't if the first one is D, in another test i did every key didn't work with all the movements that were called before it, so if i have left right down up in this order, left works fine, right doesn't accept left as second command ecc., i hope that this helps understand a bit more, sorry if it was messy i don't really know how to explain it @AdrienG.

Comment: Even as you accepted an answer as *useful, and I expect no better*: Please try and [find a title making question&answer useful for others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @greybeard yeah sorry i should change it, thanks for remembering me

Comment: I am bad at making titles so the current title is the best I could come up with, sorry if it is still not a good title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you want to reduce cyclomatic complexity to make debugging and figuring out logic easier. Cyclomatic complexity can usually be identified by having a number of `if` statements nested inside each other.  Try:

```
// The code below should go in Update since you're polling input
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) CanUp = true;
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W)) CanUp = false;
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) CanRight = true;
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D)) CanRight = false;

// The code below should go into FixedUpdate since you're manipulating a rigidbody
if (CanUp) {
     rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);              
}

if (CanRight) {
     rb.MovePosition(rb.position + Vector2.right * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);              
}
```

With the above code, when you press W it will set CanUp true until you take your finger off W.  If you press D it will set CanRight to true until you take your finger off D.  If both W and D are pressed, the character will move right (regardless of which was pressed first or last).  If you take your finger off one of the buttons and keep the other down, it will move in the direction of the pressed button.

If you want the most recently pressed button to control the direction when multiple buttons are pushed, you will need to keep track of when each key was pressed and incorporate that into your if statement i.e

```
if (CanUp && UpTimePressed <= RightTimePressed)
{
    // Move up
}
```

Comment: In the end, I used the TimePressed tip that you gave me, it worked fine and now I have what I wanted

Comment: Good to hear.  You could also maintain a list of button presses that is ordered from most recent to least recent to do the same thing.  It might be easier code to maintain over time. But if it works, that's all that really matters.